# PHP with MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to create a website using MongoDB to store user credentials (usernames and passwords). I would like to use PHP since I'm familiar with it but am having trouble with the syntax behind nearly everything in this regard (due to the updated php-mongodb driver). Are there any online resources to help, specifically, with adding and deleting information from a database? Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its a bit late but you can refer to this  basic tutorial on php mongodb. http://programmerblog.net/php-mongodb-tutorial/
hope this helps  any body in future also

Answer (score 2):

For Driver Connection issue you can check this link : [PHP mongodb driver check connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063872/php-mongodb-driver-check-connection)

---

To use MongoDB with PHP, you need to use MongoDB PHP driver. Download the driver from the url [Download PHP Driver](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html). Make sure to download the latest release of it. Now unzip the archive and put php_mongo.dll in your PHP extension directory ("ext" by default) and add the following line to your php.ini file −

```
extension = php_mongo.dll
```

**Make a Connection and Select a Database**

To make a connection, you need to specify the database name, if the database doesn't exist then MongoDB creates it automatically.

Following is the code snippet to connect to the database −

```
<?php


// connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

When the program is executed, it will produce the following result −

```
Connection to database successfully
Database mydb selected
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped!

Comment: Welcome @VishalA, Accept answer if you satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at below link which explains all about mongodb and php from scratch

https://www.sitepoint.com/building-simple-blog-app-mongodb-php/