# PHP mongodb driver check connection

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Trying to check connection with `mongodb` server using `php` driver manager! I googled many times to get the method like `$DriverManager->checkConnection()` or any property like `$DBmanager->connected`!

Current output from php var_dump `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Manager)#10 (2) {
  ["uri"]=>
  string(24) "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
  ["cluster"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I checked by starting the database server and then without running the server! There is no difference between `var_dump` results!

Any help?

Comment: Why do you need it? just execute any command, and check for errors.

Comment: Wanna make sure my program have enough resources to run on web!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB\Driver\Manager is the main entry point to the extension. It is responsible for maintaining connections to MongoDB (be it standalone server, replica set, or sharded cluster).

No connection to MongoDB is made upon instantiating the Manager. This means the MongoDB\Driver\Manager can always be constructed, even though one or more MongoDB servers are down.

Any write or query can throw connection exceptions as connections are created lazily. A MongoDB server may also become unavailable during the life time of the script. It is therefore important that all actions on the Manager to be wrapped in try/catch statements.

```
final MongoDB\Driver\Manager {
/* Methods */
final public __construct ([ string $uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/" [, array $uriOptions = [] [, array $driverOptions = [] ]]] )
final public MongoDB\Driver\WriteResult executeBulkWrite ( string $namespace , MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite $bulk [, MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern $writeConcern ] )
final public MongoDB\Driver\Cursor executeCommand ( string $db , MongoDB\Driver\Command $command [, MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference $readPreference ] )
final public MongoDB\Driver\Cursor executeQuery ( string $namespace , MongoDB\Driver\Query $query [, MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference $readPreference ] )
final public MongoDB\Driver\ReadConcern getReadConcern ( void )
final public MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference getReadPreference ( void )
final public array getServers ( void )
final public MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern getWriteConcern ( void )
final public MongoDB\Driver\Server selectServer ( MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference $readPreference )
}
```

var_dump()ing a MongoDB\Driver\Manager will print out various details about the manager that are otherwise not normally exposed. This can be useful to debug how the driver views your MongoDB setup, and which options are used.

```
<?php $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var_dump($manager); ?>
```

Reference : [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php)

Comment: Hello S N Tiwari ! [ Can you answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282664/php-mongodb-driver-query-array-columns)